# FTP login not authorizing through PHP methods

Tags: php, ftp

I'm having trouble connecting to my ftp server in PHP.  I'm able to log in using the telnet command from the cmd prompt, so the server/user/password is correct, but when I attempt to connect using PHP I get an error:

> Warning: ftp_login() [function.ftp-login]: Login incorrect. in
>   /hermes/bosweb/web232/b2323/ipg....

When I comment out my server/user/pass and replace with a public anonymous ftp server the code works (as shown below).  I've been searching for an answer for the past week but still have no clue what I'm missing or where else to look.  Also, I'm a php/server newbie, so it might be something really simple.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
    /*
    // (does not work)
    $ftp_server = "ftp.*****.com";
    $ftp_user = "******";
    $ftp_password = "*****";
    */

    $ftp_server = "ftp.gnu.org";
    $ftp_user = "anonymous";
    $ftp_password = "none";


    /* connect */
    $ftp_connection = @ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    if (!$ftp_connection) die('could not connect.');

    /* login */
    $ftp_login = @ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);
    if (!$ftp_login) die('could not login.');

    /* enter passive mode */
    $ftp_passive = @ftp_pasv($ftp_connection, true);
    if (!$ftp_passive) die('could not enable passive mode.');

    /* get listing */
    $ftp_listing = ftp_nlist($ftp_connection, "."); 
    foreach ($ftp_listing as $file){
        echo "<div>".$file."</div>";
    }

    ftp_close($ftp_connection);
?>
```

Comment: We assume your ftp port = 21, and no proxies?

Comment: What about removing the `@` so you see if there are any warnings?!

Comment: Can you log in on the ftp server with the username and password you use in the script? Are you using the correct port?

Comment: Removing @ sign will give the Warning mentioned at beginning of post.

Comment: Have you looked at the ftp server's logs to see what' happening on the server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, rookie php mistake.  I was trying to access my ftp server from php code on that server...  I guess that doesn't work.  I ran code from another server and works fine.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able to, please make sure to 'accept' your answer so that others may learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 2):

You may find it easier to abandon the ftp extension completely and just use the normal file system functions:

```
// Download a file and store the data in $data
$data = file_get_contents('ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.tld/somefile.txt');

// Loop the contents of the root directory
$dp = opendir('ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.tld/');
while ($file = readdir($dp)) {
  // Do stuff
}
closedir($dp);

// Upload a file
file_put_contents('ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.tld/somefile.txt','This is the file data');

// Upload a file from the local file system
$local = fopen('/path/to/my/file.ext','r');
$remote = fopen('ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.tld/somefile.txt','w');
stream_copy_to_stream($local,$remote);
```

You will probably find this easier to work with, as a lot of the leg work is done for you, and it will likely make your code more portable - not every server has the FTP extension installed. You can do more complicated stuff by creating a [stream context](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), which can be used with most file system functions.

Comment: Thanks DaveRandom, very useful functions.  Turns out I made a rookie mistake and was trying to ftp into my server from code running on that same server.  The posted code works great as-is.